# excepción:infracción de acceso de escritura en VS c++ al asignar memoria con malloc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manejo-de-memoria

Al ejecutar este código

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class huge{
public:

    huge(int bytes) :bytes(bytes) {
        size = sizeof(T);
        maxi = (bytes / size)+1;
        data = (T*)malloc(bytes);
        for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
        max_value = 1 << 8 * size;
    }

    int gmax() {
        return maxi;
    }

    int gbytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    huge operator=(huge x) {
        //data = (T*)malloc(x.gbytes());
        maxi = x.gmax();
        for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = x[i];
        return x;
    }

    huge operator=(T x) {
        data[0] = x;
        for (int i = 1; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
        return x;
    }

    huge operator+(T x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        y = *this;
        for (int a = 0; x!=0; a++) {
            if (x >= (max_value - y[a]-1) && y[a] != 0) {
                //cout << y[a] << '+' << x << "; x=1"<<endl;
                y[a] += x;
                x = 1;
            }
            else {
                //cout << y[a] << '+' << x << "; x=0"<<endl;
                y[a] += x;
                x = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator+=(T x) {
        for (int a = 0; x != 0; a++) {
            if (x >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += x;
                x = 1;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += x;
                x = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    huge operator+(huge x) {
        int maximax = (x.gmax() > maxi) ? maxi : x.gmax();
        T resto=0;
        for (int a=0; a < maximax; a++) {
            if (resto >= (max_value - x[a]-1) && x[a] != 0) {
                x[a] += resto;
                resto=1;
            }
            else {
                x[a] += resto;
                resto = 0;
            }
            if (data[a] >= (max_value - x[a]-1) && x[a] != 0) {
                x[a] += data[a];
                resto++;
            }
            else {
                x[a] += data[a];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    huge operator+=(huge x) {
        int maximax = (x.gmax() > maxi) ? maxi : x.gmax();
        T resto = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < maximax; a++) {
            if (resto >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += resto;
                resto = 1;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += resto;
                resto = 0;
            }
            if (x[a] >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += x[a];
                resto++;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += x[a];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    bool operator==(huge x){
        int a = 1;
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++)a = a && (x[i] = data[i]);
        return a;
    }

    bool operator<(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] > data[i];
        return 0;
    }

    bool operator>(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] < data[i];
        return 0;
    }

    bool operator>=(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] < data[i];
        return 1;
    }

    bool operator<=(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] > data[i];
        return 1;
    }

    huge operator<<(int x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        y = *this;
        //cout << endl << !(*this)<<", "<<x << endl;
        T r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
        int z = 1;
        while (x >= 8 * size) {
            x /= 2;
            z *= 2;
        }
        T rec = (size - 1 + 7 * size) - x;
        //cout << x << ',' << z << endl;
        for (int e = 0; e < z; e++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
                r1 = (unsigned int)y[i] >> rec;
                //cout << !y << "<<"<<rec<<'='<<(y[i]>>rec) << ',' << r1 << endl;
                r1 = r1 >> 1;
                //cout << !y << "<<"<<x<<endl;
                y[i] = y[i] << x;
                //cout << !y << endl;
                y[i] = y[i] + r2;
                r2 = r1;
            }
        }
        //cout << !y << endl;
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*(T x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            y += *this;
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*=(T x) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            *this += *this;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    huge operator*(huge x) {
        huge y(bytes), rec(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.gmax(); i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < maxi; e++) {
                rec = x[i];
                //cout <<endl<< !rec << endl;
                rec = rec * data[e];
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                rec = rec << 8 * size * (i + e);
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                y += rec;
                //cout << !rec << endl;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*=(huge x) {
        huge y(bytes), rec(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.gmax(); i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < maxi; e++) {
                rec = x[i];
                //cout <<endl<< !rec << endl;
                rec = rec * data[e];
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                rec = rec << 8 * size * (i + e);
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                y += rec;
                //cout << !rec << endl;
            }
        }
        *this = y;
        return y;
    }

    char* operator!() {
        char* out;
        out = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size * 16 + 5));
        sprintf_s(out, size * 2 + 5, "");
        int act = 0;
        for (int i = maxi-1; i >=0; i--) {
            if ((data[i] != 0 || i == 0) && act == 0) {
                act = 1;
                sprintf_s(out, size * 16 + 5, "%x", data[i]);
            }
            else if (act == 1)sprintf_s(out, size * 16 + 5, "%s%08x", out, data[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }

private:
    int bytes;
    T *data;
    T size;
    int maxi;
    int max_value;

};

int main() {
    unsigned int x = (1 << 8 * sizeof(unsigned int)) - 1;
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = x>>sizeof(int)*8-1;
    x = x >> 1;
    printf("\n%x\n", x);
    huge<unsigned int> y(8);
    y = (1 << 8 * sizeof(unsigned int))-1;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    y = y + 1+12;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    //y = y << 32;
    y = y * y + 1 + 0x10000000;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

escrito en c++ en Visual Studio 2017 se produce una excepción en la linea 13:

```
for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
```

**Se produjo una excepción:infracción de acceso de escritura.
this->data fue 0x1110112.**

Sin embargo cuando defino data como un array y comento la linea del malloc:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class huge{
public:

    huge(int bytes) :bytes(bytes) {
        size = sizeof(T);
        maxi = (bytes / size)+1;
        //data = (T*)malloc(bytes);
        for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
        max_value = 1 << 8 * size;
    }

    int gmax() {
        return maxi;
    }

    int gbytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    huge operator=(huge x) {
        //data = (T*)malloc(x.gbytes());
        maxi = x.gmax();
        for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = x[i];
        return x;
    }

    huge operator=(T x) {
        data[0] = x;
        for (int i = 1; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
        return x;
    }

    huge operator+(T x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        y = *this;
        for (int a = 0; x!=0; a++) {
            if (x >= (max_value - y[a]-1) && y[a] != 0) {
                //cout << y[a] << '+' << x << "; x=1"<<endl;
                y[a] += x;
                x = 1;
            }
            else {
                //cout << y[a] << '+' << x << "; x=0"<<endl;
                y[a] += x;
                x = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator+=(T x) {
        for (int a = 0; x != 0; a++) {
            if (x >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += x;
                x = 1;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += x;
                x = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    huge operator+(huge x) {
        int maximax = (x.gmax() > maxi) ? maxi : x.gmax();
        T resto=0;
        for (int a=0; a < maximax; a++) {
            if (resto >= (max_value - x[a]-1) && x[a] != 0) {
                x[a] += resto;
                resto=1;
            }
            else {
                x[a] += resto;
                resto = 0;
            }
            if (data[a] >= (max_value - x[a]-1) && x[a] != 0) {
                x[a] += data[a];
                resto++;
            }
            else {
                x[a] += data[a];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    huge operator+=(huge x) {
        int maximax = (x.gmax() > maxi) ? maxi : x.gmax();
        T resto = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < maximax; a++) {
            if (resto >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += resto;
                resto = 1;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += resto;
                resto = 0;
            }
            if (x[a] >= (max_value - data[a] - 1) && data[a] != 0) {
                data[a] += x[a];
                resto++;
            }
            else {
                data[a] += x[a];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    bool operator==(huge x){
        int a = 1;
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++)a = a && (x[i] = data[i]);
        return a;
    }

    bool operator<(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] > data[i];
        return 0;
    }

    bool operator>(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] < data[i];
        return 0;
    }

    bool operator>=(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] < data[i];
        return 1;
    }

    bool operator<=(huge x) {
        if (x.gmax() != maxi)return 0;
        for (int i = maxi - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (x[i] != data[i]) return x[i] > data[i];
        return 1;
    }

    huge operator<<(int x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        y = *this;
        //cout << endl << !(*this)<<", "<<x << endl;
        T r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
        int z = 1;
        while (x >= 8 * size) {
            x /= 2;
            z *= 2;
        }
        T rec = (size - 1 + 7 * size) - x;
        //cout << x << ',' << z << endl;
        for (int e = 0; e < z; e++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++) {
                r1 = (unsigned int)y[i] >> rec;
                //cout << !y << "<<"<<rec<<'='<<(y[i]>>rec) << ',' << r1 << endl;
                r1 = r1 >> 1;
                //cout << !y << "<<"<<x<<endl;
                y[i] = y[i] << x;
                //cout << !y << endl;
                y[i] = y[i] + r2;
                r2 = r1;
            }
        }
        //cout << !y << endl;
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*(T x) {
        huge y(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            y += *this;
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*=(T x) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            *this += *this;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    huge operator*(huge x) {
        huge y(bytes), rec(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.gmax(); i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < maxi; e++) {
                rec = x[i];
                //cout <<endl<< !rec << endl;
                rec = rec * data[e];
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                rec = rec << 8 * size * (i + e);
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                y += rec;
                //cout << !rec << endl;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    huge operator*=(huge x) {
        huge y(bytes), rec(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.gmax(); i++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < maxi; e++) {
                rec = x[i];
                //cout <<endl<< !rec << endl;
                rec = rec * data[e];
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                rec = rec << 8 * size * (i + e);
                //cout << !rec << endl;
                y += rec;
                //cout << !rec << endl;
            }
        }
        *this = y;
        return y;
    }

    char* operator!() {
        char* out;
        out = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size * 16 + 5));
        sprintf_s(out, size * 2 + 5, "");
        int act = 0;
        for (int i = maxi-1; i >=0; i--) {
            if ((data[i] != 0 || i == 0) && act == 0) {
                act = 1;
                sprintf_s(out, size * 16 + 5, "%x", data[i]);
            }
            else if (act == 1)sprintf_s(out, size * 16 + 5, "%s%08x", out, data[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }

private:
    int bytes;
    T data[100];
    T size;
    int maxi;
    int max_value;

};

int main() {
    unsigned int x = (1 << 8 * sizeof(unsigned int)) - 1;
    printf("%x\n", x);
    x = x>>sizeof(int)*8-1;
    x = x >> 1;
    printf("\n%x\n", x);
    huge<unsigned int> y(8);
    y = (1 << 8 * sizeof(unsigned int))-1;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    y = y + 1+12;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    //y = y << 32;
    y = y * y + 1 + 0x10000000;
    cout << endl << !y << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

el problema se soluciona.

¿A que se debe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instancias `huge` con `unsigned int` y `8` en `main`:

```
huge<unsigned int> y(8);
```

El tamaño (`sizeof`) de `unsigned int` es cuatro bytes, por lo que `maxi` tiene valor tres:

```
maxi = (bytes / size)+1;
//     (  8   /   4 )+1 = 3
//            2      +1 = 3
```

Reservas ocho bytes de memoria, que interpretas como punteros a `T`:

```
data = (T*)malloc(bytes);
```

Sabiendo que `T` es `unsigned int` y que cada uno de ellos ocupa cuatro bytes, `data` es capaz de almacenar **dos `T`**. Pero tú actúas como si hubiera **tres**:

```
for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;
//                 3              ^ <--- 'i' será 0, 1 y 2
//                                       ... pero las únicas posiciones legales son 0 y 1
```

Acceder a memoria fuera de la memoria solicitada es comportamiento indefinido, con lo que el programa podría haber *funcionado* o podría haber causado un error (como infracción de acceso) o podría haber hecho que expulsaras demonios de tus fosas nasales; en este caso ha pasado lo segundo.

> Sin embargo cuando defino data como un array y comento la línea del `malloc` el problema se soluciona.

No. El problema no se soluciona, el problema es exactamente el mismo: accedes a memoria fuera de la memoria solicitada (no has solicitado memoria para `huge::data`), con lo que el programa podría haber *funcionado* o podría haber causado un error (como infracción de acceso) o podría haber hecho que expulsaras demonios de tus fosas nasales; en este caso ha sucedido lo primero.

---

No me voy a andar con rodeos. Tu código es un desastre. Estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero usas herramientas de [c](/questions/tagged/c) como `malloc`. En C++ se usa `new`/`delete` en lugar de `malloc`/`free` que por cierto éste último no lo estás usando aunque deberías.

La función `malloc` carece de tipado por lo que es propensa a errores. Tu código podría ser más seguro substituyendo `T*` por `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Al escribir `maxi=(bytes/size)` como sugeriste me sale una excepción en la linea `for (int i=0; i < maxi; i++) data[i] = 0;`: **Excepción producida en 0x002A1770 en numeros n-bit.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al escribir en la ubicación 0x00000000.**

Comment: En ningún momento he sugerido que escribas `maxi=(bytes/size)`. Te sugerí que abandonases la idea de controlar la memoria manualmente y, dado que estás programando en [tag:c++] usases `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: Gracias, Con `std::vector<T>` se arregla y el problema antes era que devolvía `T x=-1` como un `huge` con `bytes = -1` en `huge operator+(T x)` con lo que el malloc no asignaba memoria.

Comment: Es que **NO DEBES USAR `malloc` MIENTRAS PROGRAMAS EN [tag:c++]**. Si realmente quieres usar memoria dinámica, usa `new` y `delete`; entre las bondades de `new` encuentras que mantiene los tipos de datos y no te permite pedir memoria negativa.